# Stop future commenting on specific post

Tags: comments

As the title says, I don't want to hide existing comments or disable future comments for all posts. I want to stop visitors from creating new comments on specific post/page.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

When you are editing the post or page. You can disable comments from the "Discussion" box. By default this box is hidden.

**Show the Discussion meta box**

If you don't see a box labeled `Discussion`:

1. Open the `Screen Options` by clicking the tab near the upper right-hand corner of the screen with the name `Screen Options`.
2. Check the checkbox before `Discussion`.

**Disable comments**

In the "Discussion" box:

1. Uncheck the checkbox for `Allow Comments.`
2. Save you post